# CK Editor - Hidden text from MS Word gets pasted

Tags: ckeditor, copy-paste, ckeditor4.x

When a user is copying from MS Word and pasting it in a text area, even the hidden text is getting pasted.

How to filter or avoid pasting of hidden characters in CK Editor (Version: 4.4.7)?

Browsers: Chrome and IE 11